# Show text block between start and end date (within date range) in magento 2

Tags: magento2

How can I display a text block between two dates?
I already a stored start and end date in db. I would like to display a shipping bar on the homepage from  April to May (stored in db).

Comment: Actually the dates already available in cms block right(https://prnt.sc/n7c9rv)? how you stored the start date and end date? Is that new table?

Comment: ya, i  have a stored a from and to date  in my custom table https://prnt.sc/n7cbnm

Comment: What's mean by shipping bar? You want to filter the blocks based on the dates right?

Comment: Please paste the collection factory code....

Comment: Shipping bar is my custom module, https://prnt.sc/n7cghx

Comment: Actually, collection factory code is needed then only we can apply filter for that code

Comment: ok  i  will create a collection factory then i will update a code  here